# Bootstrap div size positioning

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a page to display two media items, like a video chat.

The remote video will be full screen and my video should be in a small box in the bottom right corner.

I am using Bootstrap but cannot work it out as myVideo is always on the left hand side:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="vw-100 vh-100 bg-primary">remoteVideo</div>
    <div class="float-right fixed-bottom bg-light" style="height: 200px;width: 200px;">myVideo</div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

i can help u regarding this u just have to give margins i have also faced these issues so u have to give margin left and upside using css rule i will include the code hope it will help u :

```
<div class="float-right fixed-bottom bg-light" style="margin-left : x px;margin-top: x px; height: 200px;width: 200px;">myVideo</div>
```

and believe me it is best way to do it i have also used it many times !!

Comment: comment if u got that